# Drinker's Principle

Tags: predicate, isabelle

I came across a proof in Isabelle/HOL that shows the Drinker's Principle. I do understand the entire proof; however, I do not understand very well the next proof case in the Drinker's Principle proof:

```
  assume "∀x. drunk x"
  then have "drunk a ⟶ (∀x. drunk x)" for a ..
  then show ?thesis ..
```

Why does the proof also prove "**drunk a ⟶ (∀x. drunk x)**"? I think it is enough **∀x. drunk x** to show **∃x. drunk x**.

The entire proof as follows:

```
theorem Drinker's_Principle: "∃x. drunk x ⟶ (∀x. drunk x)"
proof cases
  assume "∀x. drunk x"
  then have "drunk a ⟶ (∀x. drunk x)" for a ..
  then show ?thesis ..
next
  assume "¬ (∀x. drunk x)"
  then have "∃x. ¬ drunk x" by (rule de_Morgan)
  then obtain a where "¬ drunk a" ..
  have "drunk a ⟶ (∀x. drunk x)"
  proof
    assume "drunk a"
    with ‹¬ drunk a› show "∀x. drunk x" by contradiction
  qed
  then show ?thesis ..
qed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it is enough ∀x. drunk x to show ∃x. drunk x.

That's what we are actually doing: the `for a` at the end of the the statement

```
then have "drunk a ⟶ (∀x. drunk x)" for a ..
```

is Isar's way of saying that there is a witness a of "drunk a ⟶ (∀x. drunk x)". The next line of the proof then uses this to prove the version of the statement with the existential premise.